# Why webpack still generates to old directory bundle files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, frontend, web-deployment

I have a simple app using webpack to compile my js that has one 
entry point as `./src/app.js` and 
output as `./public/dist/app.bundle.js`.

Previously the output directory **was** `./dist/app.bundle.js`

On  webpack `--watch` mode any time I make some modification to src code it generates to old path `./dist/app.bundle.js` that file as well as to new directory?? Please tell what is wrong

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app.js"),

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
        filename: "./public/dist/app.bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/public/",
    }
};
```

npm -v 3.10.10

node -v v6.10.2

webpack: 3.10.0

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app.js"),

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist"),
        filename: "app.bundle.js",
        publicPath: "dist",
    }
};
```

`output.filename`
Specifies the name of each output file on disk. You must not specify an absolute path here! The `output.path` option determines the location on disk the files are written. `filename` is used solely for naming the individual files.

`output.path`
The output directory as an absolute path (required).

`output.publicPath`
The `publicPath` specifies the public URL address of the output files when referenced in a browser. For loaders that embed `<script>` or `<link>` tags or reference assets like images, `publicPath` is used as the `href` or `url()` to the file when it's different than their location on disk (as specified by `path`). This can be helpful when you want to host some or all output files on a different domain or on a CDN. The Webpack Dev Server also uses this to determine the path where the output files are expected to be served from.

Refer to docs [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#output)

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the `output` config in your `webpack.config` as shown below.

```js
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app.js"),

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/public/",
    }
};
```

Refer: [Webpack Output](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#output)

Answer (score 0):

Please try [clean-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-webpack-plugin)  - It is a webpack plugin to remove/clean your build folder(s)

To use it, follow these steps:

1. Install clean-webpack-plugin

> npm install --save-dev clean-webpack-plugin

2. Adjust your code

```
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app.js"),
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
        filename: "./public/dist/app.bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/public/",
    },

}
```